# Rails: The path `/Users/admin/work/sandbox/rails` does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've some problem to run a rails api project:

I'm using rbenv, and here are my infos:

```
rbenv -v  =>  rbenv 0.4.0
ruby -v   =>  ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]
bundle-v  =>  Bundler version 1.11.2
rails -v  =>  The path `/Users/admin/work/sandbox/rails` does not exist.
```

anyone can help me please? thanks a lot.

Comment: What is in your current directory? Can you add the output of `ls -l` and `pwd`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem install rails`. If you switched ruby versions recently with rbenv, then you will have to download all your gems for that version of ruby if you haven't before.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the cause that some locale gem has been mentioned in your Gemfile. That gem might you have not given permission.
It can be in the following way:

```
group :development do
  gem 'some_gem', path: '/some/path/to/my/gem'
end
```

Comment that gem and run bundle. It will work